# How do I attach a scrollbar to a listbox in a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

Apologies for the dumb question, as you can probably tell, I am extremely new to Python. I am trying to attach a scroll bar to a list in a frame, I can scroll up/down the list, but I can only attach it to the frame for some reason. When I try to attach it to listbox, the listbox disappears.

Here is the code:

```
wipLotListBox = Listbox(tab_printFGWO)
wipLotListBox.insert(1,"Test1")
wipLotListBox.insert(2,"Test2")
wipLotListBox.insert(3,"Test3")
wipLotListBox.insert(4,"Test4")
wipLotListBox.insert(5,"Test5")
wipLotListBox.insert(6,"Test6")

scrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(tab_printFGWO,orient=VERTICAL,command=wipLotListBox.yview)
scrollBar.place(x=700,y=365)
wipLotListBox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
wipLotListBox.place(x=700,y=365)
```

Here is what it looks like:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place` is almost always the wrong choice. Both `pack` and `grid` are much better.

Assuming that the scrollbar and listbox are the only two widgets in `tab_printFGWO`, here's the easiest way to do it:

```
scrollBar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
wipLotListBox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Fair enough, however, I have multiple widgets.

Comment: @Vik: It's a good idea (and maybe even a best practice) to create a frame just for the listbox and scrollbar, so that you can treat the two together as a single unit. you can then put that frame in your larger app with any method you choose.

Comment: Yeah, I could work with that. Thanks for letting me know that it is the best practice. I really appreciate it!